# Server Request Timeout Error for Flask Application in Heroku using gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, heroku, request, timeout

I have tried increasing the timeout in Procfile but I am still facing a request timeout error when I process some data on server. after 30 sec of putting request to server server timeouts. Is there any way to increase this request timeout?

I am getting the category and page no from user and then scraped the data from website and when its actually busy in scraping the server timeouts after 30 sec but still the request is processing in backside.

I am using Heroku with gunicorn and my Procfile settings are:

```
web gunicorn main:app --timeout 60 --workers=3 --threads=3 --worker-connections=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to increase the HTTP timeout over 30 seconds.

It looks like you need a different approach where the users do not hang waiting for the response to be processed and trasmissed. You could consider:

1. a page showing "Working in progress", which reloads every 30 sec (checking if a background process has completed)
2. notify the users (email, browser notification) once the request has been processed by the backend

Comment: How to use a background process as I have used redis butt I am getting error in redis

Comment: When a request arrives create a Python thread which performs the work, then update the DB or Redis. You web page should access the DB/Redis to see if there is already an output of the background thread. Or you can ask the user to refresh the page (it is easier probably to start with)

Comment: For the Redis errors it is best to create a new question if you can figure out what is going on